# snap edge to edge in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, snapping

Pls see my attachment , i'm in edit mode and i want to move the selected edge along the red arrow direction so the edges will perfectly snap and overlap to target edge ( vertex A will snap to B). I tried using snap set to vertex and closest and doesn't work. Any idea how to do this ?

[image]

Comment: Try selecting the first edge, double tap G and take it to the last one. After that remove doubles by pressing W and selecting remove doubles

Comment: is this https://i.imgur.com/6MGL360.gif what you are trying to do?

Comment: *"I tried using snap set to vertex and closest and doesn't work"* what doesn't work? The described is the correct way to do this

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way: switch to vertex mode, select the vertex you want to move, and then edge slide (GKEY GKEY) it until it is adjacent to the node.  You now have a doubled vertex.  Select both vertices and merge them (ALT-M -> merge at center).  Alternately you can enable Auto merge before you edge slide.[image: Auto merge]